# Winform designed to get html from websites not working

Tags: c#, url

I am creating a C# windows form that is designed to access websites and display their HTML. However, the methodology that I am using seems to only be working with sites that don't include www. (or at least I think that's what's happening.) I'm not very good at this sort of thing, so I apologize if I missed something obvious. Many thanks in advance, here's the code:

```
string urlAddress = "https://www.pintrest.com"; //using Pinterest for testing     
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The error I keep getting is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

I don't understand what is wrong with that URL. What's going on?

Comment: There is an error in your url. Try `https://www.pinterest.com`

Comment: @schlonzo While that's true, I'd have expected a different [error/exception](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SOyY2i) ... dotnetfiddle doesn't seem to have a problem with the overall Format of that Uri : https://dotnetfiddle.net/XV5W2C

Comment: With correct url seems to work: [dotnetfiddle.net/tkxMFu](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tkxMFu)

Comment: wait, hold on. that seems to have fixed it. Thanks!